# What to use to split (slice) a huge photo when Photoshop won't work?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, software-recommendation, slices

I have a very large image that's over 80,000 by 80,000 pixels. It has to be saved in Photoshop as a PSB or PNG. I have it sectioned into many 5,000 x 5,000 pixel slices and need to export all of these slices.

From everything I'm seeing, Photoshop [doesn't seem to allow](https://feedback.photoshop.com/photoshop_family/topics/save_for_web_greyed_out) slicing of images that are this big.

What options exist for slicing up a file this big into tiles?

Comment: Perhaps Acrobat since it can [print to pdf using tiling](https://helpx.adobe.com/acrobat/kb/print-posters-banners-acrobat-reader.html) **or** [posterazor](http://posterazor.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: Automated slicing is for web-sized images. You could simply use some guides, duplicate images, and crop and export manually.

Answer (score 3):

Affinity Photo (which reads PSDs as well as most typical image and photo types) is specced to handle 65.5 Gigapixel (256000 x 256000) images - this may be your best bet.

Bear in mind that at a colour depth of 24 bits per pixel, each pixel takes up 3 bytes of memory, so if you're working in RAW, and have a lot of layer effects & filters, you may simply run out of available RAM before you reach that software-imposed top cap.

Comment: and GIMP can handle 262144px x 262144px images, and Photoshop 300000px x 300000px.

Comment: @BillyKerr -  Query for clarification: if PS claims to handle 300K Px images w/out issue, why the issue which OP has posted?

Comment: I think probably because slicing was designed for web-sized images, not massive images.